# Проблема в понимании работы метода append объекта Worksheet

Tags: python, openpyxl

Появилась необходимость заполнения данными таблицы Excel. Ниже представлен код, который мне не до конца понятен:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('myfile.xlsx')
ws = wb.active 
# data for filling Excel table
rows = (
   (88, 46, 57),
   (89, 38, 12),
   (23, 59, 78),
   (56, 21, 98),
   (24, 18, 43),
   (34, 15, 67)
    )
for row in rows:
    ws.append(row)
wb.save('my_changed_file.xlsx')
```

После выполнения кода выше, я ожидал увидеть заполненную таблицу Excel данными из кортежа. Таблица заполнилась со второй строчки, хотя я ожидал увидеть таблицу заполненную с первой строчки. Не понятно почему, не вижу предпосылок для такого поведения кода.

Answer (score 2):

У меня проучилось воспроизвести описанное поведение если в исходном файле хотя бы в одном столбце в первой строке поставить пробел, т.е. технически первая строка - не пустая, но данных невооруженным глазом не видно.

Если `myfile.xlsx` пустой, то данные добавляются с первой строчки.

---

**UPDATE:** если в исходном файле не было формул и графиков, то удобнее будет использовать Pandas для подобных задач:

```
import pandas as pd   #   pip install pandas

df = pd.DataFrame(list(rows), columns=['colA','colB','colC'])

df.to_excel(r"/path/to/my_changed_file.xlsx")
```

PS если

Comment: Заполнив вторую строчку пробелом, заполнение ячеек началось с третьей строки.)) То есть получается заполнение начинается с первой пустой строки.

Comment: @ХачатурСаркисян, `.append()` - переводится как "добавить", а не "заполнить". И да, добавление происходит в __конец__ Excel листа.

Comment: В исходном -- шаблонном файле предусматриваются ячейки с условным форматированием и формулами.

Answer (score 1):

Есть такой нюанс, что первая строка всегда существует, даже если таблица совсем пустая. Количество строк, упрощённо говоря, рассчитывается как `число переносов строк + 1`, что даёт 1 даже для файла нулевой длины. Попробуйте на том же файле выполнить `print(ws.max_row)`. А раз первая строка всегда есть, то метод `append` добавляет данные лишь со второй строки.

Решения:

1. Просто добавьте названия столбцов, чтобы первая строка не была пустой.
2. Можно перед вставкой данных проверять таблицу на пустоту, вставлять в нужное место. И тогда уже использовать надо не `append`, а `insert_rows`.

---

**Update.** Интересный пример:

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

def show_content(ws):
    print('Sheet size:', ws.max_row, ws.max_column)
    for row in ws.rows:
        print('\t'.join(map(lambda x: str(x.value), row)))


filename = 'myfile.xlsx'

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
wb.save(filename)
show_content(ws)

wb = load_workbook(filename)
ws = wb.active 
show_content(ws)
```

> Sheet size: 1 1
>   Sheet size: 1 1
>   None

То есть, даже изначально созданная таблица имеет не нулевой размер, хотя цикл по содержимому ничего не показывает. Предполагаю, что в самой библиотеке есть такой баг, который при большинстве юзкейсов просто не замечаются или обходится стороной.

Comment: Почему же когда я использую метод create_worksheet() - заполнение с помощью функции append начинается с первой строки, как я и ожидаю?

Comment: @ХачатурСаркисян честно говоря, подробностей не знаю, но по всей видимости, в библиотеке есть неточности, которые приводят к разным объектам при создании пустой таблицы и при считывании из пустого файла – в первом случае строк видимо реально 0, хотя и показывает одну. Добавил любопытный пример кода.